# Number of elements of the inner arrays of a multidimentional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, sizeof

I am new to C and by reading online I understand that with sizeof() I can have the memory that is allocated to it in bytes, and if I divide it by an element inside it or the data type, I can have the number of elements of an array.

I am trying to use this logic with a 2d multidimensional array and I'm having problems with the inner arrays.

Here is a code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYLEN(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]))

int main(void) {
    int input[][20] = {
        {90, 1349, 430, 198, 677, 1869, 1692, 1098, 761, 677, 1004 ,0},
        {163, 642 ,2445, 1032, 2738 ,1591 ,3950 ,1600 ,651, 0},
        {1730 ,3067 ,1956, 723 ,1307 ,417 ,2838 ,1486 ,3114 ,3698 ,1881 ,0},
        {2337, 5131 ,1527 ,5042 ,953, 0},
        {80, 389, 413 ,209 ,219, 100 ,191, 419, 181 ,473 ,271 ,0},
        {22 ,3900 ,4057, 439 ,2642, 1447 ,3553, 2244, 3328, 3924, 1486, 400, 2394 ,0},
        {2870, 621 ,3779, 3508, 3729, 2985, 1083, 1384, 3782 ,2606, 637, 0},
        {1400, 108 ,472 ,1411, 10, 453, 1631, 1331, 0},
        {808 ,1584, 2545, 2294, 1983, 842 ,447, 807 ,3711, 1067, 490, 0},
        {435 ,14 ,261, 395, 340, 340, 25, 114, 178 ,52 ,232 ,19, 54, 0},
        {6181 ,2026, 4061, 7796 ,5192 ,958, 4190, 965 ,2642, 5082, 2579, 1872 ,0},
        {2030, 106, 579, 36, 1147 ,111 ,1393 ,459, 209, 1847, 1171, 415, 725, 1245, 0}
    };

    printf("%d", ARRAYLEN(input));
    printf(" ");
    printf("%d", ARRAYLEN(input[0]));

    printf(" ");
    printf("%d", sizeof(input[0]) / sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

The first `printf()` returns `12` which is right, but the second `printf()` (and third) return `20` which is the memory I've allocated to it but not the number of elements that each one has, which is what I am looking for in order to use on a for loop.

Can someone explain how can I do this? Or what I am doing wrong?

I can't find an answer/explanation anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: array size are fixed, you have an array of 12 array of 20 integer., if you want something more flexible use an array of pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has potential undefined behavior on architectures where `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(int)`. Either use `%zu` in your `printf` format strings or cast the arguments as `(int)`.

You should also parenthesize the `ARRAYLEN` macro argument more carefully.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAYLEN(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))

int main(void) {
    int input[][20] = {
        {90, 1349, 430, 198, 677, 1869, 1692, 1098, 761, 677, 1004 ,0},
        {163, 642 ,2445, 1032, 2738 ,1591 ,3950 ,1600 ,651, 0},
        {1730 ,3067 ,1956, 723 ,1307 ,417 ,2838 ,1486 ,3114 ,3698 ,1881 ,0},
        {2337, 5131 ,1527 ,5042 ,953, 0},
        {80, 389, 413 ,209 ,219, 100 ,191, 419, 181 ,473 ,271 ,0},
        {22 ,3900 ,4057, 439 ,2642, 1447 ,3553, 2244, 3328, 3924, 1486, 400, 2394 ,0},
        {2870, 621 ,3779, 3508, 3729, 2985, 1083, 1384, 3782 ,2606, 637, 0},
        {1400, 108 ,472 ,1411, 10, 453, 1631, 1331, 0},
        {808 ,1584, 2545, 2294, 1983, 842 ,447, 807 ,3711, 1067, 490, 0},
        {435 ,14 ,261, 395, 340, 340, 25, 114, 178 ,52 ,232 ,19, 54, 0},
        {6181 ,2026, 4061, 7796 ,5192 ,958, 4190, 965 ,2642, 5082, 2579, 1872 ,0},
        {2030, 106, 579, 36, 1147 ,111 ,1393 ,459, 209, 1847, 1171, 415, 725, 1245, 0}
    };

    printf("%d %d %d\n",
        (int)ARRAYLEN(input),
        (int)ARRAYLEN(input[0]),
        (int)(sizeof(input[0]) / sizeof(int)));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `12 20 20`, as expected:

- `12` is the number of elements in the array `input`: 12 rows of 20 `int`.
- `20` is the number of elements in the array `input[0]`, as per the definition.
- `20` is again the number of elements in the array `input[0]` as `int` is the type of its elements.

The fact that you have fewer elements in the initializer for some or all of the sub-arrays does not change their size, each sub-array has 20 elements as specified in the definition `int input[][20]` and the remaining elements are initialized to `0`. The number of sub-arrays is determined by the compiler from the initializer.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question. ("Why each subarray has the size of 20, even if they have different amount of initializers")

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I think it does now.  When the code has undefined behavior it is usually a moot point trying to make sense from its output.

Comment: I think I understand now. So when I initialize an array in C and I don't give a value to a certain index the compiler defaults it to 0. Thanks

Comment: @JoãoNeves: yes that's correct. you cannot omit initializers in the middle of the array, so it only works for the trailing elements. However you can use C99 initializers to only specify selected elements and the compiler will initialize the other ones to 0.

Comment: @chqrlie: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of 12 rows of 20 elements each. The number of rows is defined by the number of initializing rows you give. The number of elements is determined by the number 20.

The size given by `(sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0]))` is the number of rows.

The size given by `(sizeof(input[0]) / sizeof(input[0][0]))` is the number of elements on a row

The size given by `(sizeof(input) / sizeof(input[0][0]))` is the number integers, i.e. rows x columns.

The following code prints the array:

```
for (int i=0; i<ARRAYLEN(input); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<ARRAYLEN(input[0]); j++) {
        printf("%d ",input[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be reduced to:

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3};

ARRAYLEN(array) == 10
```

If you explicitly specify a size for your array (`int x[N]` instead of `int x[]`), then the array will always have the size you specified, regardless of the amount of initializers inside of the curly braces.

Elements without initializers are initialized with zeroes.

In other words, there is no difference between

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3};
```

and

```
int array[10] = {1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

---

Also, as others have noted, your macro should be defined as

```
#define ARRAYLEN(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
```

to avoid problems with operator precedence if the macro argument happens to be an expression rather than a simple array name.

The value you get from this macro should be printed with `%zu`, since it's of type `size_t`, not `int`.